# Make first column of p-table a different colour to the rest

Tags: html, css, primeng, p-table

Does anyone know how to make the first column of a p-table a different colour to the rest?
And then the other columns alternating colours?
I can only seem to find a way of doing this with rows? Currently the style class is just this -

```
[styleClass]="'p-datatable-gridlines'"
```

which makes the rows alternating colours, not the columns.

Comment: have you tried using nth-of-child or nth-of-type?

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<body>
 <meta charset-utf"8"> 
 <color>="blue"</color>





</body>


</head>
<color>"blue"</color>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).